# Building OpenJDK - Corba issue

Tags: windows, corba, java

I'm trying to build OpenJDK 7 on WinXP x32 but getting a Corba error:

```
make[4]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Projects/OpenJDK/jdk7/corba/make/com/sun'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Projects/OpenJDK/jdk7/corba/make/com'
abs_src_zip=`cd C:/Projects/OpenJDK/java_libs/java_libs/openjdk7/output_32/corba
/dist/lib ; pwd`/src.zip ; \
( cd ../src/share/classes ; find . \( -name \*-template \) -prune -o -type f -pr
int | zip -q $abs_src_zip -@ ) ; \
( cd C:/Projects/OpenJDK/java_libs/java_libs/openjdk7/output_32/corba/gensrc ; f
ind . -type f -print | zip -q $abs_src_zip -@ ) ;
File not found - *-template

zip error: Nothing to do! (/cygdrive/c/Projects/OpenJDK/java_libs/java_libs/open
jdk7/output_32/corba/dist/lib/src.zip)
FIND: Parameter format not correct

zip error: Nothing to do! (/cygdrive/c/Projects/OpenJDK/java_libs/java_libs/open
jdk7/output_32/corba/dist/lib/src.zip)
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'C:/Projects/OpenJDK/java_libs/java_libs/openjdk
7/output_32/corba/dist/lib/src.zip' failed
make[2]: *** [C:/Projects/OpenJDK/java_libs/java_libs/openjdk7/output_32/corba/d
ist/lib/src.zip] Error 12
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Projects/OpenJDK/jdk7/corba/make'
make/corba-rules.gmk:42: recipe for target 'corba-build' failed
make[1]: *** [corba-build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Projects/OpenJDK/jdk7'
Makefile:251: recipe for target 'build_product_image' failed
make: *** [build_product_image] Error 2
```

Looks like *-template files haven't been generated during Corba build (I didn't find any *-template file in Corba directory) and therefore src.zip archive hasn't been created.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build OpenJDK via alexkasko's scripts: https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds